# Guardar un get() en una variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy programando en Python3 con tkinter y cuando intento guardar el resultado de un cuadro de texto (un Entry) en un .get() y uso esa variable en un Label, no aparece, por ejemplo:

```
varNum=IntVar()
cadrotexto=Entry(root)
numeroRecogido=cuadrotexto.get()

miLabel=Label("Escogiste el número:" + numeroRecogido)
```

¿Es así como declaro una variable como numérica y es así como guardar el valor del Entry en una variable?

Comment: ¿La idea es mostrar en el Label el número ingresado en el Entry?¿Usas algún botón para aceptar lo insgresado?¿O quieres que se vaya mostrando al mismo tiempo que se va ingresando en el Entry?¿O que se muestre al pulsar Enter? Ten en cuanta que no asocias en ningún momento la variable al Entry para empezar.

Comment: La idea es cuando pulse un botón, aparezca en el Label por ejemplo: As escogido el número: (Y aquí el número introducido en el Entry). Pero no sé si como he mostrado antes está bien o mal. A parte de eso, sé como hacer que al pulsar el botón aparezca ese Label, pero si pongo Label(text="As introducido el número:" + cuadrotexto.get()) Si aparece el resultado, pero en lugar de poner cuadrotexto.get() pongo numeroRecogido, no aparece nada

Answer (score 1):

Primero debes tener en cuanta que cuando haces:

```
numeroRecogido=cuadrotexto.get()
```

obtienes efectivamente **el contenido del `Entry` como una cadena en ese instante** y esta cadena la asocias a la variable `numeroRecogido`. Si posteriormente modificas el `Entry` la variable no va a cambiar por tanto.

La llamada a `get` debe producirse en el instante en el que quieras obtener el contenido del `Entry`, no justo después de la inicialización del widget, porque obtendrás como es lógico una cadena vacía. Si usas un botón para procesar lo ingresado en el `Entry`, la lectura del mismo ha de ser dentro de la propia callback asociada al botón.

Por otro lado, puedes asociar una `StringVar` tanto al `Label` como al `Entry`, la cual si es modificada cuando el contenido del widget lo es y viceversa. Puedes asociar una `IntVar` también al `Entry`, pero se lanzará una excepción si lo ingresado no es convertible a un entero.

Un ejemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk


def aceptar():
    try:
        n = int(var_texto.get())  # Obtenemos el número de la StringVar
    except ValueError:            # Si lo ingresado no es un entero
        var_lbl.set(f"No escogiste un número válido")
    else:                         # Si lo ingresado es un entero
        var_lbl.set(f"Escogiste el número: {n}")


root = tk.Tk()

var_texto = tk.StringVar()
var_lbl = tk.StringVar()

mi_label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var_lbl)
var_lbl.set("Escoge un número") # Contenido inicial del Lable
mi_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

cuadro_texto = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var_texto)
cuadro_texto.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

btn_aceptar = tk.Button(root, text="Aceptar", command=aceptar)
btn_aceptar.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!